# How to survive on earth like planet with no supplies at the start

Tags: space-colonization, survival

Before I start, I would like to explain the purpose of this series. A few days ago, I had a big project where I had to a design a prompt for everyone to write about. So for the next few weeks, I will be sending out different prompts for you guys to answer. These are all opened ended so don't worry about getting any right or wrong answers.

This is the prompt that my close friend gave me:

Imagine this : you are now stuck on a planet with no supplies, no water, no food, nothing. You can surely live here ; it got oxygen and all the necessities to live. How would you survive?

I hope you like it (but sorry for the bad quality, I'm not the best writer)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131338/discussion-on-question-by-tempzapex-how-to-survive-on-earth-like-planet-with-no).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're gonna die.**

Earth-like-planets can be very inhospitable for a castaway without proper kit. Plunked in the middle of an ocean without a boat, you will quickly drown. In the Antarctic or Sahara or Himalayas during the wrong season, your unprotected survival may be measured in minutes or hours.

You must be lucky enough to land in a hospitable location on the planet. Not too hot or cold, not too wet or dry.

Then you run into the next problem: If the chemistry is compatible so you can survive after eating the local fodder, then it seems likely that the local microbes on that fodder and soil and water and air can eat YOU. You might not feel sick, you may not develop a fever, but after a few days you will begin to hemorrhage, weaken, and then succumb.

However, you might give as good as you get -- your own voracious microbes may cause a mass extinction on that nameless world.

Comment: Well, of course you are going to die. The real question is: Can you do it in an interesting way, and have an interesting journey towards your demise?

Comment: Best practice is ***not*** to answer unfocused questions, especially when they're in the close queue.

Comment: The answer is actually isn't bad, maybe too focused on a specific direction, but it highlights some problems which will be relevant for the proposed setting. //@Burki we aren't here to entertain ppl, it is work done by authors, we are here to help those authors to write better work, help in a specific way - by sharing our expertise applied to a suggested scenario, with the inclination of doing so using science and such stuff, rational measurable and such, even when it is about magic - when you see different answers it is just a sign we are not always successful in doing so.

Answer (score -1):

**NOT A BIG PROBLEM**

If "all the necessities to live" are present, it should not be a major problem. This would mean that you can breathe the air and eat the food, and there are materials that can be used for tools and clothing.

First order of business would be to find a source of drinking water. Stick close to that and forage easy edibles like fruits, nuts and eggs

Next, find a sharp stone or make one by throwing rocks at each other (flint is very good for this). Use this to fashion a stick into a pointy spear. Now you can defend yourselves from beasts and hunt fish and animals to eat, and you can make fire by banging rocks for sparks or rubbing sticks against each other - not easy, but once you have the fire going, you keep it going by regularly adding wood or burying the hot ashes. You can bake clay pots in the fire to store and carry stuff and eventually bake bricks for a real house to replace the quick lean-to you have made from sticks, straw and leaves.

The sharp stone can be used to skin animals for their fur (smoke them or pee on them for preservation), and you can fashion needles from bone and thread from intestines, Now you have clothes, fur shoes and bags. Make a bow from wood and bone bound with intestines, which you also use for bowstrings (or, more simply, make a sling). Improve your spear with a bone tip. Improve your stone-working skills enough to fashion a stone axe and a proper stone knife.

There, you are all set. :-)

Comment: Best practice is ***not*** to answer unfocused questions, especially when they're in the close queue.

Comment: a bow is a too much effort - atlatl and you are set - practice and success are there, around the corner. I downvote this one because it focuses on a sequence of actions instead of priorities, and why those priorities. Focusing on actions in such a general setting makes no sense. In this regard, another answer is better.